# Jabber notification via Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to send a Jabber notification via the `failure` section of a `Jenkinsfile`? [This spinet shows how to do it for irc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/ircnotify-commandline/ircNotify.groovy) which makes me think that Jabber would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It is not possible … yet

Jenkins [issue 36826](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36826) is a feature request for this to happen.